# I visualized it as a heatmap to see how the features are correlated, but only one specific feature is not correlated. Why is this happening?

Tags: kaggle

Initial feature description:

The values ​​of the name feature are changed to "Mr", "Mrs", "Miss", "Master", and "Other", and the values ​​are converted to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 respectively. (dtype is int64)

```
sns.heatmap(data.corr(),annot=True,cmap='RdYlGn',linewidths=0.2,annot_kws={'size':20})
fig=plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(18,15)
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

I visualized it as a heatmap to see the correlation of the Titanic features in Kaggle, but only the feature called Initial does not show the correlation. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: I'll try to solve it myself and leave an answer. I accidentally created two columns, Initial and Initial. There was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an initial column and an initial column, so there seems to be a typo, so please check the code.